# In C++11, what is the point of a thread which "does not represent a thread of execution"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Looking over the new threading stuff in C++11 to see how easily it maps to pthreads, I notice the curious section in the `thread` constructor area:

> **thread();**
>   *Effects:* Constructs a thread object that does not represent a thread of execution.
>   *Postcondition:* get_id() == id()
>   *Throws:* Nothing.

In other words, the default constructor for a thread doesn't actually seem to *create* a thread. Obviously, it creates a thread *object,* but how exactly is that useful if there's no backing code for it? Is there some other way that a "thread of execution" can be attached to that object, like `thrd.start()` or something similar?

Comment: C++11 is scaring you and me both at this point, luckily I'm a kernel dev now so standards aren't changing on me anymore :)

Comment: I think they mean that the thread constructor doesn't create an actual thread, it doesn't call the operation system, doesn't allocate stack/other resources and generally doesn't create a stopped thread. I think this is in place so people would know they are not wasting anything by creating the thread before starting it (other than some flags storage).

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: kernel dev afraid from standard changes? If I recall correctly each new processor breaks something in the kernel or adds a feature that requires a lot of rewrite to implement.

Comment: @Dani but it's not like C has changed much so overall it's the same and hardware is easy enough to get around. C++11 looks completely different to me and quite a bit of people, I guess it just takes some getting used to

Comment: Jesus: C++11 only adds stuff, all your old code still works, it's just... well, old. There are a number of better ways to do things now. And `std::thread` is a library addition, like `<complex>` was in C99.

Comment: @rubenvb: Well, not _all_ of it... :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Is there some other way that a "thread of execution" can be attached to that object, like thrd.start() or something similar?

```
// deferred start
std::thread thread;

// ...

// let's start now
thread = std::thread(functor, arg0, arg1);
```

`std::thread` is a MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable type. So that means that in code like `std::thread zombie(some_functor); std::thread steal(std::move(zombie));` `zombie` will be left in a special, but valid, state associated with no thread of execution. The default constructor comes free in a sense since all it has to do is put the object into that exact state. It also allows arrays of `std::thread` and operations like `std::vector<std::thread>::resize`.

Comment: Actually... your thread will have a thread id of 0. There is no internal native thread context. It's just a placeholder type for arrays and stl containers.

Answer (score 24):

It means the same thing as this:

```
 std::vector<int> emptyList;
```

`emptyList` is empty. Just like a default-constructed `std::thread`. Just like a default-constructed `std::ofstream` doesn't open a file. There are perfectly reasonable reasons to have classes that default construct themselves into an empty state.

---

If you have an empty thread:

```
std::thread myThread;
```

You can actually start the thread by doing this:

```
myThread = std::thread(f, ...);
```

Where `f` is some callable thing (function pointer, functor, `std::function`, etc), and `...` are the arguments to be forwarded to the thread.

Answer (score 10):

Not just guessing:

"thread object" refers to a `std::thread`.

"thread of execution" refers to the [OS's collection of hardware registers that represent a thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29).

C++11 is doing nothing but papering over the OS's API for access to OS threads in order to make C++ threading portable across all OS's.

> **thread();**
>   *Effects:* Constructs a thread object that does not represent a thread of execution.
>   *Postcondition:* get_id() == id()
>   *Throws:* Nothing.

This means a default constructed `std::thread` does not refer to a thread of execution that the OS has produced.

A `std::thread` can be given a new value, and thus begin to refer to an OS thread of execution by a move assignment statement:

```
std::thread t;  // Does not refer to an OS thread
//...
t = std::thread(my_func);  // t refers to the OS thread executing my_func
```

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing, but it simply means that the thread is not started. In other words, it is just an object like any other - there's not necessarily an actual OS thread behind it. To put it another way, if threads were implemented on top of pthreads, creating a C++11 thread object doesn't necessarily call pthread_create() - that only need happen when the thread is started.

Comment: So, ..., my query would then be the second part of my question: "how do you start it?"

Comment: Maybe you can't. After all, if you've used the zero-argument constructor, you haven't specified anything for the thread to *do*. That does, I suppose, lead to the question of why you can create such a useless object, though.

Comment: Rather: As Luc Danton points out in his answer below, you can use the assignment operator to start the thread.